# Boolean not keeping value

Tags: java, swing, graphics, boolean

I have an application where the user draws lines. There is a JButton btnClear which, when the user clicks, must clear the drawings, so that the user can draw anew. I use an ActionListener on btnClear to know when it is clicked. I set a boolean Clear so that the correct IF statement is executed in paintComponent(). However, the boolean Clear keeps a False value in paintComponent() although I set it to True just before repaint(). Why is it so?

Note: I tried setting the frame's background to red just for to test the boolean in paintComponent().

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Clipping extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener
{
    static JFrame frame;
    static JComboBox cboDraw;
    static JButton btnClear;
    static JButton btnClip;

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    boolean FirstPoint;
    boolean Clear = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                CreateFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void CreateFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Clipping");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Clipping());
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Clipping()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        PopulateToolBar(toolbar);
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.WEST);

        addMouseListener(this);
        cboDraw.addMouseListener(this);
        btnClip.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);

    }

    private static void PopulateToolBar(JToolBar toolbar)
    {
        String[] cboList = {"Line", "Polygon"};
        cboDraw = new JComboBox(cboList);
        cboDraw.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(70,30));
        btnClip = new JButton("Set clip area");
        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");

        toolbar.add(cboDraw);
        toolbar.addSeparator();
        toolbar.add(btnClip);
        toolbar.addSeparator();
        toolbar.add(btnClear);

        cboDraw.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnClip.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnClear.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        toolbar.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        toolbar.setFloatable(false);
        toolbar.setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (cboDraw.getSelectedIndex() == 0) //draw line
        {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        }
        else if (Clear == true)
        {
            frame.setBackground(Color.red); //ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSE
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() != cboDraw) //to prevent line coordinates from being saved when selecting from combobox
        {
            if (cboDraw.getSelectedIndex() == 0) //user wants to draw line
            {
                if (FirstPoint == false) //first coordinates
                {
                    x1 = e.getX();
                    y1 = e.getY();
                    FirstPoint = true;
                }
                else //second coordinates
                {
                    x2 = e.getX();
                    y2 = e.getY();
                    repaint();
                    FirstPoint = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getSource() == btnClear)
        {
            Clear = true;
            repaint();
            Clear = false;
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your paintComponent method override. Call this first, else, clear won't work.

Note that in your current code, this will not work for you since you're painting incorrectly in that you're not specifying, iterating through and drawing **all** the lines that need to be drawn within your paintComponent method. The way to solve this is via one of two ways:

- Either create a `List<Line2D>` such as an `ArrayList<Line2D>`, fill it in your MouseListener/MouseMotionListener code, and then iterate through this List in your paintComponent method, drawing each line. If you do this, then your clear button's action would be to simply clear the List via `clear()` and call `repaint()`. No need for a boolean.
- Or you could draw your lines onto a BufferedImage, and then draw the BufferedImage in your paintComponent method via the `g.drawImage(...)` method. If you do this, always check that the image is not `null` before drawing. Then in your mouse listening code, you'd draw to this image. In your clear button action, you'd create a new BufferedImage, or clear the current BufferedImage.

---

Also get rid of `setBackground(...)` calls from within paintComponent as they really shouldn't be in there.

For example of use of an ArrayList of lines:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanelViaArrayList extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color LINES_COLOR = Color.black;
   private static final Color DRAW_LINE_COLOR = Color.pink;
   private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
   private List<Line2D> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
   private int x1 = 0;
   private int y1 = 0;
   private int x2 = 0;
   private int y2 = 0;


   public DrawPanelViaArrayList() {
      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
      add(new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear")));
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // for smooth graphics
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      // first draw the temporary line to show the user
      // where he's drawing
      if (x1 != x2 && y1 != y2) {
         g2.setColor(DRAW_LINE_COLOR);
         g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      }

      // then draw all the lines held in the linesList.
      Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
      g2.setColor(LINES_COLOR);
      g2.setStroke(STROKE); // draw thicker lines
      for (Line2D line2d : lineList) {
         g2.draw(line2d);
      }
      g2.setStroke(oldStroke); // reset stroke
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         x1 = e.getPoint().x;
         y1 = e.getPoint().y;
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         x2 = e.getPoint().x;
         y2 = e.getPoint().y; 
         Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
         // add line to ArrayList
         lineList.add(line);
         x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = 0;
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         x2 = e.getPoint().x;
         y2 = e.getPoint().y; 
         // draw temporary line
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ClearAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         lineList.clear();
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanelViaArrayList());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

And what the heck, a BufferedImage version

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanelViaBufferedImage extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color LINES_COLOR = Color.black;
   private static final Color DRAW_LINE_COLOR = Color.pink;
   public static final Color CLEAR_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
   public static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
   private int x1 = 0;
   private int y1 = 0;
   private int x2 = 0;
   private int y2 = 0;
   private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_W, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


   public DrawPanelViaBufferedImage() {
      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
      add(new JButton(new ClearAction("Clear")));

      // if the GUI is to be re-sizeable, then consider adding a 
      // ComponentListener here, and resizing the BufferedImage in it
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // for smooth graphics
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      // first draw the temporary line to show the user
      // where he's drawing
      if (x1 != x2 && y1 != y2) {
         g2.setColor(DRAW_LINE_COLOR);
         g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      }

      // then draw the BufferedImage if not null
      if (img != null) {
         g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
      }
   }

   // size of our GUI
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         x1 = e.getPoint().x;
         y1 = e.getPoint().y;
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         x2 = e.getPoint().x;
         y2 = e.getPoint().y; 
         Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);

         // draw to the BufferedImage
         Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
         g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g2.setStroke(STROKE);
         g2.setColor(LINES_COLOR);
         g2.draw(line);
         g2.dispose();
         x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = 0;
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         x2 = e.getPoint().x;
         y2 = e.getPoint().y; 
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private class ClearAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ClearAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
         g2.setBackground(CLEAR_COLOR);
         g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
         g2.dispose();
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawPanelViaBufferedImage());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: With super.paintComponent(g), when I draw a line, it clears the line that is already present (the user must be able to draw as many lines as she wants).

Comment: @Phantom: you need to then either create an ArrayList of Line2D or else draw to a BufferedImage which is cleared by clear.

Comment: @Phantom: for an example of what I mean about using an ArrayList of Line2D, please see code above.

Comment: @Phantom: please see edit to answer that hopefully clarifies what I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

You should just do `setBackground(Color.red);` to call it on your JPanel instead of the JFrame

Answer (score 0):

I think your `actionPerformed` and `mousePressed` are both executed at the same time. In `mousePressed` your `if` condition inside `mousePressed` is satisfied also if `btnClear()` is the source. So `repaint` method is called anyway, and you see no changes.